# how to install scala plugin for latest eclipse ide (version 2020-03)

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse version= 2020-03 (4.15.0)

I tried to install scala plugin through eclipse market place
but it is giving errors:=

Unable to connect to repository http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e47/scala212/dev/site/content.xml

Connect to download.scala-ide.org:80 [download.scala-ide.org/128.179.67.43] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Is there any alternative to install scala plugin for eclipse ide or for scala do we need to work with
scala ide for eclipse(oxygen) ?

Comment: Scala plugin for Eclipse is no longer developed. If you want to have IDE with Scala support use IntelliJ with Scala plugin. Alternatively there is [metals](https://scalameta.org/metals/)

Comment: Yes as Mateudz already said, the Scala eclipse plugin is basically dead. And even if you manage to install it, it won't work with newer versions of the language. And if you use it with older versions, it still would be pretty slow and would produce a lot of false errors all the time. Do you have any particular reason for wanting to use it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yeah completely agree with you and Mateusz. I was familiar with eclipse and hence was looking to use scala in it.But as addressed above I am giving up eclipse option and switching to IntelliJ.

Comment: @AbhiK if you like eclipse, you may want to see if there is an LSP implementation fo it and use [**metals**](https://scalameta.org/metals/). - Oh, it seems it is and metals supports it!

Comment: `IntelliJ` is a paying experience that not everyone enjoy. And when all your projects are on `Eclipse` they are on `Eclipse`. The poster didn't asked you advertisings about your favorite IDE. Don't change his question.

Comment: Try without the 'content.xml' or may be you are behind a firewall/proxy. It certainly did work for me, refer answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Scala plugin (scala version 2.12) for Eclipse pretty much installs on Eclipse 2020-06. The [Update site URL](http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e47/scala212/stable/site) surely works. The JDK used is AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.9 with OpenJ9. Refer image below.

The plugin may or may not be under development but it certainly still works.

[image]

Comment: The link is unreachable : Unknown Host: http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e47/scala212/dev/site/content.xml
download.scala-ide.org

Comment: AccessDeniedAccess Denied7XY63Y6QYCE9XWSECOHxaWAp/lwNJPc5ZycICCeTg8i+dMJVpQqEUZ0ZPEWjPU0PFr3xWl1qAWRcyNu0v3i3YM6aU1M=