# How do I have integrated support for Scala inside newer versions of Eclipse (2023-06)?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide, scala-metals

I have a large java project with a bit of scala in it and it builds sucessfully with gradle on command line.
Inside the IDE, it builds sucessfully thanks to an old plugin named [Scala-IDE](https://scala-ide.org/) which is not maintained anymore and binds me to an older version of Eclipse, which is unsatisfying.
I found another plugin named [metals](https://olafurpg.github.io/metals/docs/editors/eclipse.html) but its update [site](http://scalameta.org/metals-eclipse/update/) appears to be broken.
Also, I tried to build the project directly from https://github.com/scalameta/metals-eclipse but unfortunately, the project is archived and I also have a build error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition P:\git\metals-eclipse\target-platform\target-platform.target: Could not find "com.google.gson/2.7.0.v20170129-0911" in the repositories of the current location
```

I could find this inside the file `target-platform.target`:

```xml
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
  <unit id="com.google.gson" version="2.7.0.v20170129-0911"/>
  <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/latest-R/"/>
</location>
```

After updating the URL from `https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/latest-R/` to `https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20220830213456/repository/` in `target-platform.target` I have a new build error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve target definition:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext 3.0.47.202305042122
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.google.guava 31.1.0.jre requires 'java.package; com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal [1.0.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext 3.0.47.202305042122 depends on: java.package; com.google.common.base [31.1.0,32.0.0)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition P:\git\metals-eclipse\target-platform\target-platform.target: See log for details -> [Help 1]
```

How can I fix the build ?
Any other solution to have full scala support inside Eclipse ?

Comment: That target is trying to use the latest Eclipse Orbit release but that now has GSON 2.10.1. The last Orbit release with GSON 2.7.0 was `https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20220830213456/repository/` you could try that.

Comment: I have a new error message now: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20220830213456/: No repository found at https://download.eclipse
.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20220830213456.

Comment: Use https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20220830213456/repository/ - "repository" at the end

Comment: Background: https://github.com/scalameta/metals-eclipse/discussions/20

Comment: Is it a requirement that you have to use Eclipse?

Comment: The project is incompatible with IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: In what way? Does it fail to import or is there some licensing concerns? (I saw people even here who were not aware that IJ Community Edition - and Scala plugin - has been [OSS for a few years](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) and only proprietary plugins are closed and payed for). Because if it works in metals then is almost certainly can be imported through BSP.

Comment: "The project uses Gradle 2.14.1 which is incompatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2." Also it does not propose to import all projects in a workspace and also did not try to build.

Comment: I remember having an issue with intellij working with an old version of gradle. The solution was open the project with an old version of intellij that is compatible with gradle. [The project uses Gradle 2.12 which is incompatible with IDEA running on Java 10 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447285/the-project-uses-gradle-2-12-which-is-incompatible-with-idea-running-on-java-10) might help in this case

Comment: ok but giving up an older version of Eclipse for an older version of Intellij isn't satisfying.

Comment: have you checked the link to the question that mention an [issue trying to run a gradle 2.12 project from intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447285/the-project-uses-gradle-2-12-which-is-incompatible-with-idea-running-on-java-10)? The suggestion is to [switch the boot jdk](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following discussions

- [any eclipse alternative to scala](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/any-eclipse-alternative-to-scala-ide/5219)
- [how to install scala plugin for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972044/how-to-install-scala-plugin-for-latest-eclipse-ide-version-2020-03)
- [Future plans for the Eclipse Metals plugin](https://github.com/scalameta/metals-eclipse/discussions/20)

eclipse doesn't have good support for scala. Unless you need something specific from eclipse, the best options you have today are

- [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea-for-scala.html)
- [metals](https://scalameta.org/metals/): it has integration with many IDEs and editors such as vs code, vim, sublime, emacs.

Comment: The project is incompatible with IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: What's the reason? Intellij is just one of the options. Maybe metals is ok for your project? Without knowing why eclipse is required, is hard to provide a proper suggestion. What kind of features does eclipse offer?

Comment: as far as I understood, metals is a language server, not a standalone offline tool, I'm not supposed to build online.

Comment: It's a language server. That's correct. Not sure if with build online you are saying that you need to connect to some remote server. It works offline. When you use Metals from VS Code, the IDE connects to the local server and interact with Metals and based on the response take some action. Maybe [Language Server Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) and [Build Server Protocol](https://build-server-protocol.github.io/docs/specification) can help to understand better.

Comment: Thanks I understand better now, but does this include full support of multi module gradle project written in java integrating some pieces of scala? Gradle support seems to be provided by something called bloop but that requires changing the build.gradle files.

Comment: [Bloop](https://scalacenter.github.io/bloop/docs/what-is-bloop) is a build server. It has two main goals. 1) Compiles, tests and runs Scala code as fast as possible, 2) Integrates easily with build tools, command-line applications, editors and custom tooling. You can install metals in VS Code, open a [gradle project](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/build-tools/gradle) and click on `import build` button. It will automatically update your gradle files to install de bloop plugin for gradle. You can also do it manually, but it is not required.

Comment: There is a closed issue that talks about [gradle integration doesn't work with multi-module project](https://github.com/scalacenter/bloop/issues/1452). Looks like there is some support. Not sure if that will work with the old gradle that you are using for this project. I guess just installing vs code with metals and try to build your project to see what happens is a good try. If you can share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), edit your post or create a new one detailing better your issue and maybe you could get better suggestions

Comment: Right now, mixed Java/Scala projects are possible in metals but the support isn't great because it attempts to compile the Java side of things whilst that would be much better supported by existing Java language servers. See https://github.com/scalameta/metals-feature-requests/issues/5 . The state of combined Scala & Java tooling isn't great, even today.